# Data Binding an observable collection of strings

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyList { get; set; }
    public string MyListTitle { get; set; }
...
```

I'm populating it as follows:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass("Data"); // Populates title

myClass.MyList.Add("Test data 1");
myClass.MyList.Add("Test data 2");

myListView.DataContext = MyClass.MyList;
```

Finally, here's the XAML:

```
<ListView Visibility="Visible" x:Name="myListView" Height="Auto">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="contentScrollView">
        <TextBlock x:Name="DataItem" Text="{Binding}" />                                
    </ScrollViewer>
</ListView>
```

The result (and problem) is that I get the class name displayed once in the listview, rather than the two entries above.

Comment: so you only get `Test data 1`

Comment: No - I get the class name of MyClass (once)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first need to set the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListView` to your `ObservableCollection`

```
myListView.ItemsSource = myClass.MyList;
```

Also, you need to use a [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) to display the actual items:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock x:Name="DataItem" Text="{Binding}" /> 
 </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're binding the TextBlock that's why you receive the .ToString() of the list. What you need to bind is the [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) of your list, that way the ListView will bind its items with the ones inside your list.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this one

```
myListView.DataContext = MyClass.MyList;
```

Shall become

```
myListView.DataContext = myClass.MyList; //note the case of myClass
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">            
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="DataItem" Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>            
    </ListView>
```

and

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        myClass.MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        myClass.MyList.Add("Test data 1");
        myClass.MyList.Add("Test data 2");

        this.DataContext = myClass;
```

and

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyList { get; set; }
    public string MyListTitle { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {

    }
}
```

Result

[image]